# can i assign json keys to css classes in order to render them in React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a React class in which I am setting my state to a local json:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Maps.css";
import df3 from "./data/df3.json"

class Maps extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const data = df3;
    this.state = data
}

  render()
  {
    console.log(this.state)

    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Maps
```

When i console log the state, I see my json as expected:

```
{ "space1": {
    "0": 0.0,
    "1": 2.0,
    "2": 0.0,
    "3": 2.0,
    "4": 0.0,
    "5": 2.0,
    "6": 0.0,
    "7": 2.0,
    "8": 0.0,
},
  "space2": {
    "0": 0.0,
    "1": 0.0,
    "2": 0.0,
    "3": 0.0,
    "4": 0.0,
    "5": 0.0,
    "6": 0.0,
    "7": 0.0,
    "8": 0.0,
  },
  "space3": {
    "0": 0.0,
    "1": 0.0,
    "2": 0.0,
    "3": 0.0,
    "4": 0.0,
    "5": 0.0,
    "6": 0.0,
    "7": 0.0,
    "8": 0.0,
  }
}
```

now, I would like to trying assign a css element to each of these objects (ie space1,2,3 etc), so that a representation of each of the objects appears on the page. Not sure if there is a simple answer!

Comment: yes, for this example, I would like to have 3 divs be rendered on the page

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to parse the json:

```
const data = JSON.parse(df3);
```

Comment: Seems there's problem in your json file ie. to say could not parse the  json.

Comment: what kind of thing could cause that? when i console log it, it looks fine, just an array of objects. could it be that some of them contain kv pairs with numeric values, and others contain string values?

Comment: comes back "Valid JSON"

Comment: the json in this post is just  dummy data, on my machine i have a longer json that is coming back as valid. Do you see error in the json?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214206/discussion-between-vp9-and-bhojendra-rauniyar).